# Show that $p$ divides the number of equivalence classes of $E$ that are singletons

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group, $p$ a prime dividing $|G|$ and $X = \{(x_0,..., x_{p−1})) ∈ G^p:∏_i x_i = 1\}.$ Let $E$ be the relation defined on $X$ by $(x_0, ..., x_{p−1})E(y_0,..., y_{p−1})$ if there exists $k \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ such
that $y_{i+k} = x_i$. (The indexes are considered to live in $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, so if $i+k⩾p$, what we mean is $y_{i+k−p} = x_i$).

Show that $p$ divides the number of equivalence classes of $E$ that are singletons.

Should I find the equivalence classes of $E$ first? How could we determine it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by $G_p$?

Comment: @zed111: presumably, tuples of $p$ elements of $G$.

Comment: It seems to me that the only singleton equivalence classes $\{(x_0,...,x_{p-1}) \}$  have $x=x_i$  for $0\leq i< p.$ So you are asked to show that  $p $ divides  $|\{x\in G :x^p=1\}|.$

Comment: @user254665: indeed, I suspect this is an intermediary towards a proof of Cauchy's theorem (with the punchline being that there is at least one singleton, namely $(e, e, \ldots, e)$).

Comment: @AlexWertheim. Which theorem of Cauchy are you referring to?

Comment: @user254665: the partial converse to Lagrange's theorem which states that if $p$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ act on the elements of $X$ via
$$[k]_{p}\cdot (x_{0}, \ldots, x_{p-1}) = (x_{0+k}, \ldots, x_{p+k})$$
where (as it states in the problem) we take the indices mod $p$. The orbits of this action correspond with the equivalence classes of $X$ under the relation $E$. Now use the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Feel free to comment if you need more assistance.